# How to show text when anchor present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, anchor

If a user clicks: `<%= link_to "Sign Up", root_path(anchor: "start-here") %>`, they are brought to the sign up portion of the web page which is signified by: `<div id="start-here"></div>`

How can I show the text, "Create Challenge to Sign Up" if the user clicks the "Sign Up" button, www.livetochallenge.com/#start-here?

Not sure if javascript is needed to reveal the text or if this can be done with ruby alone. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for alt-text? (small blurb that pops up when user hovers over element)

Comment: No sorry @itdoesntwork. Like actual text to appear so no need to hover over.